# Usar alert do bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-3

Estou tentando usar o alert do bootstrap em um projeto, mas estou tendo dificuldade em faze-lo, o que tenho no momento é isso:

```
if (sNome == "" || sTel == "" || sCEP == "" ){
    $("p.erro").html("Todos os campos devem ser preenchidos");
    return false;
} else if ( !(emailFilter.test(sEmail)) || sEmail.match(illegalChars) ){
    $("p.erro").html("Por favor, informe um email válido.");
    return false;           
}
```

E estou exibindo a mensagem dessa forma:

```
<p class="erro" align="center"></p>
```

Mas gostaria de poder exibir nesse formato:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
<strong>Atenção: </strong> Todos os campos precisam ser preenchidos.</div>
```

Ao tentar fazer essa alteração a `div` do `alert` sempre fica visível, tentei fazer a alteração dessa forma:

```
$(".alert").html("Todos os campos devem ser preenchidos");
```

Mas como disse não ficou correto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode adicionar a classe `hidden` a sua div, ficaria assim:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger hidden"></div>
```

E na chamada do javascript você só precisaria adicionar o método `show` do jQuery

```
$(".alert").html("<strong>Atenção: </strong> Todos os campos devem ser preenchidos").show();
```

Comment: Olá @Felipe Nascimento, obrigado pela sugestão, alterei o código como indicado, mas agora a div não aparece com a mensagem.

Comment: Estranho, tente então substituir a função show, por .removeClass("hidden");

Comment: Grande ajuda @Felipe Nascimento, agora deu certo, novamente obrigado.